# Load swiffy page as banner

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-swiffy

I have been trying to load the html page genereated by swiffy into my site banner.  I tried iframes as was suggested in the google FAQ, but when links are clicked they only open in the iframe as per usual, but I need them to open on the current page so I tried breaking up the swiffy code into a javascript file and calling it in as shown below.  I am currently using word press, which means this is all being loaded from a header.php file, and have been trying the following code with no luck.  Any suggestions?

```
<div id="home-banner" width="916px" height="200px">
</div>
<script src="http://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v3.9/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.goaefis.com/Banner.js">
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('home-banner'), swiffyobject);
stage.start();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to deregister the WordPress jquery so you can use the google code. You can save the script inside the `<script></script>`tags as a separate document. For this example I'll call it swiftfyobject.js. It will need to go in the theme folder inside a folder named js. You can then call the script from within the themes function.php file.

Here is how it should look:

The swiffyobject.js file that goes in the js folder:

```
var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('home-banner'), swiffyobject);
stage.start();
```

The code for the functions.php file:

```
function add_themescript(){
  if(!is_admin()){
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://www.goaefis.com/Banner.js');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'swiffyobject', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/swiffyobject.js', array('jquery'));
}
}
add_action('init','add_themescript');
```

That should get you going if there aren't any conflicts with other code in the theme or plug-ins you use.